# Объявление классов внутри функций

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Можно ли объявлять классы внутри функций? А передавать созданные таким образом объекты в другие функции? Например, данный код выполняется, как задумано:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo (T x)
{
    std::cout << x.a;
}

int main() {
    struct X {
        int a = 3;
    } x;

    foo(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В аналогичном вопросе [на англоязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876069/767632) отвечают, что объявлять локальные классы и структуры можно. Однако до C++11 их было нельзя использовать в качестве параметров шаблонов, зато можно, например, для реализации фабрики (пример из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876109/767632), корректен в C++03):

```
// В .h
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
};

Base* CreateBase( const Param& );

// В .cpp
Base* CreateBase( const Params& p )
{
    struct Impl: Base
    {
        virtual void DoStuff() { ... }
    };

    ...
    return new Impl;
}
```

Начиная с C++11 их можно использовать в том числе как параметры шаблонов, то есть с C++11 ваш пример тоже корректен.

Comment: Подскажите параграф, где говорится, что с 11 стандарта можно так делать

Comment: @share_qw [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8203922/767632) ссылаются на §14.3.1/2. Говорят, что в C++03 он явно запрещает использование в параметрах, а в C++11 - не запрещает, и даже приводит пример такого использования.